# How do eigenvalues of algebraic multiplicity greater than 1 correspond to shears?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, linear-transformations

Shouldn't they only correspond to stretches?

Ax = kx, so the original vector x has been stretched by a factor k.

Comment: Shears occur when the algebraic multiplicity exceeds the geometric multiplicity.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: But why is that? From the equation, isn't stretch the only possible transformation A can perform upon an eigenvector?

Comment: $A$ does indeed perform a stretch along the line through the origin that corresponds to $x$, but it’s “missing” eigenvectors, so there are directions in which the action of $A$ can’t be described by a combination of constant-factor stretches.

Comment: @Saad The question is not what $A$ does to an eigenvector. Rather, the question is what $A$ does to a *generalized eigenvector*.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a typical example:
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 1 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{pmatrix}. $$
Clearly, $\det{(A-tI)} = (\lambda-t)^2$, but $A-\lambda I \neq 0$, so the minimal polynomial is $(\lambda-t)^2$. $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of geometric multiplicity $1$ (its one eigenvector being $(1,0)$) and algebraic multiplicity $2$. This is a shear matrix: it sends $(1,0)$ to $(\lambda,0)$ and $(0,1)$ to $(1,\lambda)$.

On the other hand, a stretching matrix with one eigenvalue in two dimensions looks like
$$ B = \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda \end{pmatrix}. $$
Here, $\det{(B-tI)} = (\lambda-t)^2$, but $B-\lambda I=0$, so the minimal polynomial is $\lambda-t$, and the eigenspace of $\lambda$ is two-dimensional, with basis $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, for example.

Now, it turns out that it is possible to choose a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ so that any linear map can be expressed as a diagonal block matrix made of upper-triangular blocks of this type,
$$ \begin{pmatrix} \lambda & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
0 & \lambda & 1 & \ddots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & \lambda & 1 \\  \end{pmatrix} $$
which is called [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), so actually these examples tell us most of what we need to know about how such matrices work. (The other piece is that an $k \times k$ matrix $U$ with $1$s on the diagonal above the main one and zeros elsewhere satisfies $U^k=0$ and $U^j \neq 0$ for $0<j<k$)

Answer (score 0):

Your misunderstanding comes from the fact that what people call multiplicity of an eigenvalue has *nothing* to do with the corresponding eigenspace (other than that the dimension of an eigenspace forces the multiplicity of an eigenvalue to be *at least* that large; however even for eigenvalues with multiplicity, the dimension of the eigenspace usually is still just$~1$). What the multiplicity (if compute from the characteristic polynomial) does do is give the dimension of the *generalised eigenspace* for the eigenvalue, which contains the eigenspace but in general is larger. What you call shear is a phenomenon that happens when the generalised eigenspace is strictly larger than the eigenspace.

So if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for$~T$, then it has an eigenspace $V_\lambda$ of dimension at least$~1$, on which $T$ acts as the scalar $\lambda$ (stretch only). But if $\lambda$ has multiplicity and the generalised eigenspace $G_\lambda$ is strictly larger than $V_\lambda$, then it contains some vectors $v$ for which $T(v)\neq\lambda v$ (so $v\notin V_\lambda$) but such that $T(v)-\lambda v\in V_\lambda$ in other words $T-\lambda I$ moves $v$ in the direction of$~V_\lambda$. This is what is called shear (more precisely for $\lambda=1$: there are fixed vectors, and also other vectors that are not fixed but mode in the direction parallel to the subspace of fixed vectors.

To see why such $v$ exist, you can consider the quotient space $G_\lambda/V_\lambda$. The operator $T$ induces an operator on this quotient, and $\lambda$ is the only eigenvalue, so there is an eigenspace of dimension at least$~1$ for$~\lambda$ in $G_\lambda/V_\lambda$. But we already formed the quotient by the eigenspace$~V_\lambda$, so the eigenspace of $G_\lambda/V_\lambda$ cannot come from this. So there are vectors $v\in G_\lambda$ whose classes in $G_\lambda/V_\lambda$ are eigenvectors, and in terms of $T$ this means that $T(v)-\lambda v\in V_\lambda$, but since an eigenvector is not zero, $v\notin V_\lambda$.